# Is there a list/guide/documentation where the GTK constants went in GTK+ 3 in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

It's been widely discussed that *a few* things changed from Python2/Gtk2 to Python3/Gtk+3. I got along with that so far, but there is one thing I am having trouble with: Where did all the constants go?

In Python 2.x I could just do `gtk.RESPONSE_OK` and now I can do (after *a lot* of trying around, I found) `Gtk.ResponseType.OK`

**Question:**  Is there any **complete and comprehensive** list/documentation of where the specific constants went?

Answer (score 3):

Please see the introspection porting guide:
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting

In terms of a "complete and comprehensive" list, the pygi-convert.sh script is probably the closest thing you will find. Its use is for porting PyGTK programs to PyGObject 3, but could very much serve as the list you are looking for:
https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/pygi-convert.sh

If you find anything missing from the script, please log a bug or even better submit a patch:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=pygobject

Answer (score 2):

This reference should really help you out:

https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/constants.html

In general this is a good page to look for PyGObject stuff:

https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/index.html

You can also search his Github account for code examples: https://github.com/lazka

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind that is that the introspector converts `GTK_ENUMTYPE_ELEMENT` to `Gtk.ENUMTYPE.ELEMENT` for gtk3 python bindings (gi). So having a look at the original Gtk+-3 .x documentation suffices (i.e. using devhelp). (why not have a look at the binding doc itself anyways?).